# going up the number without touching any button

Tags: arduino, calculator

I'm working on a calculator like something is working with how much press a button as number one in the calculator. for example, I press the button four times and the number one in the calculator is four now. But the problem is that when Arduino is on, The number is going up without touching buttons. What can I do? I'm using a number display, an Arduino UNO board, and four buttons, this is my code :

```
    #include <TM1637.h>


// this is a calculater with four buttons on pins 2 3 4 5 and a number display and the driver is TM1637 CLK on pin 13 and DIO on pin 12. after making sure you connected
// all the modules you can program these codes on your Arduino UNO. LET'S JUTS MAKE IT!

const int btn_one = 2;
const int btn_two = 3;
const int btn_three = 4;
const int btn_four = 5;
/*
int b1s = LOW;
int b2s = LOW;
int b3s = LOW;
int b4s = LOW;
*/

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int mathop = 1;


int CLK = 13;
int DIO = 12;

TM1637 tm(CLK,DIO);

void setup(){
  tm.init();
  tm.set(7);
  pinMode(btn_one, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn_two, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn_three, INPUT);
  pinMode(btn_four, INPUT);
  
}

void loop(){
  int b1s = digitalRead(btn_one);
  int b2s = digitalRead(btn_two);
  int b3s = digitalRead(btn_three);
  int b4s = digitalRead(btn_four);

  if(b1s == true){
    num1 = num1 + 1;
    displayNumber(num1);
    //digitalWrite(btn_one, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
  
}

void displayNumber(int num){   
    tm.display(3, num % 10);   
    tm.display(2, num / 10 % 10);   
    tm.display(1, num / 100 % 10);   
    tm.display(0, num / 1000 % 10);
}
```

and these are my connections:
[Connections 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLj2N.jpg)
[Connections 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfLA0.jpg)

If you can help me please send me the answer that can be so helpful to me, Thank you very much.

Comment: you input pin is floating

Comment: What can I do? I'm New in arduino

Comment: Follow a basic button tutorial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I saw your button connection circuits. The main problem is in the circuit itself. You haven't added a resistor with your button and digital input pin, thereby, making the button state being read by **digitalRead** a floating value between 0 and 1 (false value). Follow the circuit given here:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Button
It's best to use 10k ohm resistor for each button.

Secondly, why are you using **delay** of 1 second?

Comment: please don't answer off-topic questions. Stack Overlow is about coding. If you want to answer Arduino questions, we have Arduino Stack Exchange